# Rewriting url for local nginx web server

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, ubuntu-server

I've set up an ubuntu server 16.04 on a vm using VirtualBox.
I believe I have configured a self-signed certificate, and all other initial configuration correctly.

I'm trying to rewrite the url to display as:
https://subdir.hostname.com

As opposed to how its being written right now:
https://hostname.com/subdir

Here are the contents of my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;    
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;    
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here are the contents of my default_server file in sites-enabled

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name hogwarts.io;
    //This is something I changed but its not working
    return 301 https://$request_uri.$server_name.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name server.unixmen.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Using a naked `$request_uri` to represent the subdirectory is bad. You need to sanitise it with a regular expression, for example, using a `rewrite` directive:

```
rewrite ^/(\w+) https://$1.$host/ permanent;
```

You can follow it with a return statement to define the behaviour in case the regular expression fails to find a match.

The example above, redirects to the root of the subdomain, but you can also capture the remainder of the URI and pass that in the rewritten URL.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.